# How to use import a personal library in another project with Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

So I have a personal stack library, let's call it `Foo`. In `Foo`, I have a `FooModule` module file named `FooModule.hs`. 
I have another stack project called `Bar`. How do I import the `FooModule.hs` module to project `Bar`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do this all the time. In your `stack.yaml` file, add the path to the `Foo` package:

```
-- stack.yaml
packages:
- '.'
- lib/foo
```

And then in your `Bar.cabal` file you say that your build depends on `Foo`

```
-- project.cabal
...
build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                   , foo
```