# How to Make Stack See Dependencies?

Tags: haskell-stack

I have two stack projects, A and B. B depends on A; B's stack.yaml is the following:

```
resolver: lts-12.10
packages:
- .
- ../path/to/A/
```

where there exists a file ../path/to/A/stack.yaml, and `stack build` in A's directory builds successfully.

In B's directory, I `stack build --ghc-options -v`, and stack builds A, then proceeds to trying to build B, failing to find A's modules. I don't know how stack works, but the verbose output shows that GHC is looking only in ./.stack-work and ./src/ - not in A's directory. Running `stack dot` produces a diagram with nodes A and B, but no arrows between them. It's like stack is seeing A but not as a dependency of B.

`stack solver` reports that no changes need to be made.

Using latest stack (v1.7.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on [another SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395931/how-to-use-import-a-personal-library-in-another-project-with-stack): the piece I was missing was adding A's package name to the `dependencies` list in B's `package.yaml` file. This hadn't occured to be earlier, as I'd incorrectly assumed that `dependencies` was for upstream repository packages only.